# Regular expression to avoid alphanumetic Bangla numbers

Tags: regex

Please help with the following problem. For the following Bengali text:

> "না ২১তম। এয়ার ১০টি কোয়ালিটি ইনডেক্স ১০৫.৫৬ (একিউআই) স্কোর ১০৪, গতকাল
> ছিল ৭৬।"

and for the following regular expression:

> [০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯]+.[০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯]+|[০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯]+

I get the the following output:

> না **২১**তম। এয়ার **১০**টি কোয়ালিটি ইনডেক্স **১০৫.৫৬** (একিউআই) স্কোর **১০৪**, গতকাল
> ছিল **৭৬**।

However, here, it successfully detects pure numbers (here: ১০৫.৫৬)  or numbers with punctuations(১০৪ and ৭৬). However, it also detects numbers which are alphanumeric(here: ২১ from ২১তম and ১০ from ১০টি). I want to detect numbers, numbers with punctuations(bengali punctuations , and ।) but do not want to detect alphanumeric numbers (bengali alphabet: "অআইঈউঊঋএঐওঔকখগঘঙচছজঝঞযশহটঠডঢণরষতথদধনলসপফবভমড়ঢ়য়ৎংঃ‍ঁ‍্‍্য‍‍্রর্ক")

Expected Output for the input text mentioned at the beginning should be:

> না ২১তম। এয়ার ১০টি কোয়ালিটি ইনডেক্স **১০৫.৫৬** (একিউআই) স্কোর **১০৪**, গতকাল
> ছিল **৭৬**।

Tested on: regex101.com

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
([০-৯]+\.[০-৯]+|[০-৯]+)(?=[,।\s])
```

If you also need to to exclude cases when letters right before digits use

```
(?<=[,।\s])([০-৯]+\.[০-৯]+|[০-৯]+)(?=[,।\s])
```

Note, I've replaced your `.` to `\.`, as `.` is special symbol in regex meaning any 1 symbol. Also, I've changed `[০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯]` to `[০-৯]` for compactness.